# phpbb3 how to modify the profile fields?

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

Somebody knows how could I add a label underneath the profile information ? what files  have I to modify?
I want something like this :
[image]

Comment: user and groups / custom profile fields in ACP.

Comment: you mean acp_profile and acp_groups?, in the 'adm' directory?

Comment: no, you can make custom profile fields in the admin control panel.

Answer (score 3):

To add custom fields, log in to the administration control panel of your phpBB3 board, click on the Users and Groups tab, and then on the Custom profile fields link on the left. On the Custom profile fields page you'll see a drop-down menu from which you can select the type of field. There are several options: numbers, single text field, textarea, boolean (yes/no), dropdown box, date. After you select the type of field click on the Create new field button that's right next to the drop-down menu.

You'll be taken to a page with some options. The options are divided into three sections: Add profile field, Visibility options, and Language specific options. You don't have to configure everything. In the Add profile field section type a name in the field for Field identification. This is the name with which the field will be identified in the database. In the section labeled Visibility options you can choose where you want the field to be displayed (e.g. user control panel, registration screen, viewtopic screen). You can also make the field a required one; you can do this if, for example, you want to make the particular field a necessary part of the registration form.

In the section Language specific options type a name in the field for Field name. This is the name that will be visible to users. In the textarea for Field description you can also add a short explanation or description. Depending on the type of field, in this section there may also be some other options specific to the field type.

After you configure all the necessary settings click on the button Profile type specific options in the lower right corner of the screen. You'll be shown some options that are specific to the particular field type. After you're done with these options click on the Save button. If there are other language packs installed on your board, you'll be offered the chance to translate the field name, description, etc., into the particular language.

Once the custom field is created you can edit or delete it at any time from Users and Groups tab>Custom profile fields. Done!